# Retrieve the value of a key from a array

Tags: php, arrays, json, key, discord

Thanks to the discord API I managed to generate a table with different role identifiers assigned to different keys. However, I would have liked to return a text according to the selected identifier thanks to a condition but I can not do it. I used the json_decode function which returns an array in json.

Cordially,

Examples:

[image: array]

Code:

```php
  $json_context = stream_context_create($json_options);
  $userapi = apiRequest($apiURLBase);
  $guildapi = apiRequest($apiURLBase2);
  if(session('access_token')) {
    $json_get = file_get_contents('https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/538087318284795905/members/'. $userapi->id .'', false, $json_context);
    $json_decode  = json_decode($json_get, true);
    foreach($guildapi as $guild) {
      print_r($guild->name);
    }
    echo '<h3>Roles</h3>';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($json_decode);
    // This condition doesn't work 
    if($json_decode['roles'] == '581822046087020555') {
        echo 'Vous êtes premium !';
    } else {
        echo 'Vous n\'êtes pas premium !';
    }
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    echo '<h2>Roles</h2>';
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Veuillez vous connectez pour voir vos rôles !';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `roles` is **array**, you should check if required role is **`in_array`**:

```
echo '<h3>Roles</h3>';
// ...
if (in_array('581822046087020555', $json_decode['roles'])) {
    echo 'Vous êtes premium !';
} else {
    echo 'Vous n\'êtes pas premium !';
}
```

Also, if you're going to output every role, you can iterate over your array and check if current iterated value is equal to required:

```
echo '<h3>Roles</h3>';
// ...
foreach ($json_decode['roles'] as $role) {
    echo 'Role is ' . $role . '<br />';
    if ('581822046087020555' === $role) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because it's an array 
you can use foreach to get all the value of array

```
foreach($json_decode['roles'] as $role){
 if($role == "581822046087020555"){
  echo 'Vous êtes premium !';
 } else {
  echo 'Vous n\'êtes pas premium !';
 }
}
```